# FileStream to Byte[]: Windows XP vs Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-xp

I recently had to write some code that:

- UI takes a file (image)
- Converts to `byte[]
- Uploads the `byte[]` to a website (using `HttpWebRequest`. `ContentType` is `multipart/form-data`)
- Website then reads the stream, use the parameters that I sent with the file, stores the `byte[]` in a database.

This image is then used in reports and the user can download the image whenever.
And this worked fine, until we started testing it on a windows XP machine. Whenever I upload any image from the XP pc, the image wouldn't show. After some debugging and testing and writing this `multipart/form-data` to a text file,  I saw that the `byte[]` of the file differed on Windows XP vs Windows 8 (or even 7). The generated file's size differed as well.

I'm using VS2012 with .Net 4.0, and did install (and repaired again) .Net 4 on the XP pc.
I can only think that either the two operating systems encode differently or perhaps its a difference between 32-bit OS and 64-bit. Obviously I have no idea what is wrong, and don't even know where to start. I'd like to know if someone can just point me in the right direction?

Here is the UI-side code:

```
//Wrapped around each parameter. The last boundary after the byte[] file >has been omitted.
string boundary = "----------------------------" + >DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");

//Creating the httpWebRequest as multipart with "POST" method.
httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_webUploadUrl);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
httpWebRequest.Credentials = >System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

//Upload stream will be built with all the parameters, followed by the >byte[] file.
Stream uploadStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();


byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(boundary + >"\r\n");


string formdataTemplate = "\r\n--" + boundary +
"\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\";\r\n\r\n{1}";

//Parameters:
//Foreach parameter, Wrap in boundary
foreach (string key in _nvcParameters.Keys)
{
    string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, key, >_nvcParameters[key]);
    byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
    uploadStream.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);
}

byte[] netBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--");
uploadStream.Write(netBytes, 0, netBytes.Length);

//The actual file:           
uploadStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; >filename=\"{1}\"\r\n Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "uplTheFile", _fileName);
byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
uploadStream.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);

//While file is greater than buffer, write to uploadStream.
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead = 0;
long fileSize = pFileStream.Length;            
long uploadedValue = 0;

while ((bytesRead = (pFileStream).Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
{
    uploadStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    Application.DoEvents();
}
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = uploadStream.Length;
//Close the original fileStream.
pFileStream.Close();
```

The website uses UTF8. I can post it if needed, but because the `byte[]`s differ, I thought the problem might be there.

---

@Ramhound The use of long? are you referring to the `fileSize` and `uploadedValue` variables? The code is part of company's UI-side of the system, very big and I'm just starting to know my way around some parts, anyways, I've checked the Project's properties, (if that is the right place to check). At the build the Platform target is x86. Are you talking about that or something else? Sorry I'm still a student and new to c# (and vs for that matter)

I've opened both files on Windows 8 machine. The win8 file size is 6kb bigger and contains more characters, obviously.

Here is the first few lines of the array. The `_ncvParameters` are the same (as well as the file uploaded, Here is the first part of the resulting multipart-form (`ncvParameters` followed by the first few lines of the `byte[]` file):

Win8:

> ------------------------------8d00a632401f30e Content-Disposition: form-data; name="o";
>
> 25
>   ------------------------------8d00a632401f30e Content-Disposition: form-data; name="k";
>
> 2913
>   ------------------------------8d00a632401f30e Content-Disposition: form-data; name="u";
>
> 255
>   ------------------------------8d00a632401f30e Content-Disposition: form-data; name="f";
>
> Blue hills.jpg
>   ------------------------------8d00a632401f30e Content-Disposition: form-data; name="m";
>
> image/jpeg
>   ------------------------------8d00a632401f30e Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uplTheFile"; filename="Blue hills.jpg"  Content-Type:
>   application/octet-stream
>
> ‰PNG
>
> ```
> IHDR  €  à   5ÑÜä   sRGB ®Îé   gAMA  ±üa      pHYs  Ã  ÃÇo¨d  ÿ¥IDATx^ìýg—\7²­ëÿ÷¾gïî–§÷¤H9Š¢DR”—Ú{Ç6²”÷M‘yç¹V$™UÅ–úô>÷|˜@
> ```
>
> ˜ÌÄ2y×?oÝ¾øáíÛWþ±õŸ†[w€‘õøû-pëÊßnïãº·ÃØ‡uxK¾í

WinXP:

> ------------------------------8d00a639ff7bf76 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="o";
>
> 25
>   ------------------------------8d00a639ff7bf76 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="k";
>
> 2913
>   ------------------------------8d00a639ff7bf76 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="u";
>
> 255
>   ------------------------------8d00a639ff7bf76 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="f";
>
> Blue hills.jpg
>   ------------------------------8d00a639ff7bf76 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="m";
>
> image/jpeg
>   ------------------------------8d00a639ff7bf76 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uplTheFile"; filename="Blue hills.jpg"  Content-Type:
>   application/octet-stream
>
> ‰PNG
>
> ```
> IHDR         Ä‰   sRGB ®Îé   gAMA  ±üa    cHRM  z&  €„  ú   €è  u0  ê`  :˜  pœºQ<   IDATWc`    ªÕÈQ
> ```
>
> IEND®B`‚’èÊû:uÊžòÞ°Ë[=)Qä¡w¢%º2§Î~ó™‰¬½×f±¤~¯×1‰H$01#ùßÿâ‹ÿ¯¿¸äÿý‡‹—ü;üX§¿8(ýQ$?º$Ã“ÿþÃ©ÚêÀBTÿpà%•~ÖbºËá
>   þÝü8ù­Ÿ:å_ø(IÿGã‹þâ/Æ Cô¨Í.*›QV

---

@Xaqron - uploadStream is a `memoryStream`. The entire multipart-form is written to this stream, which then writes to a `byte[]`. Which gets streamed to `httpWebRequest`.

I'm pretty sure its the same image. I've tried it twice just to make sure. I'll triple-check today at the office - Yes, I've done it multiple times now. The same image produces different sizes and different `byte[]` characters.

---

Ok, I think I've found the problem. This may have been useful information, but I didn't even think this would be the issue. The file uploaded is an image, which I resize. The resizing method takes a `byte[]` (the one I thought was incorrectly encoded), writes it to a bitmap. This bitmap is then 'redrawn' to a new size with `PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb` and `InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic`:

```
if (pImage.Height < maxHeight && pImage.Width < maxWidth) return pImage;  
using (pImage)  
{  
    Double xRatio = (double)pImage.Width / maxWidth;
    Double yRatio = (double)pImage.Height / maxHeight;
    Double ratio = Math.Max(xRatio, yRatio);
    int nnx = (int)Math.Floor(pImage.Width / ratio);
    int nny = (int)Math.Floor(pImage.Height / ratio);
    System.Drawing.Bitmap cpy = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(nnx, nny, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
    using (System.Drawing.Graphics gr = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(cpy))
    {  
        gr.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Transparent);

        gr.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        gr.DrawImage(pImage,
            new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, nnx, nny),
            new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, pImage.Width, pImage.Height),
            System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
    return cpy;
}
```

I changed the `PixelFormat` mode to 'DontCare' and the `InterpolationMode` to `Default`. 
Sorry it this would've been obvious, but I thought this was handled by the .net framework?

Comment: Can you try to read the same file on two OS and print out the size of the byte[] and the first several bytes to see where the difference is?

Comment: Its not possible to use .NET Framework 4.0 with Visual Studio 2012. Make sure you force your project to compile as a 32-bit application. This will prevent any 32-bit operating system to 64-bit operating system problems. I highly suspect the use of `long` might be the reason the filesize is different between 32-bit installation of Windows XP and a 64-bit installation of Windows 8.  This is not a encoding issue since you define what the encoding is in your code.

Comment: @Bezaleel - Update your question don't use the comments to post additional information.

Comment: @Bezaleel Whats missing in your code sample is the origin of _nvcParameters. The only way the size mismatch can happen using the same Encoding is a difference of the source data set which I strongly suspect to differ on both platforms.

Comment: "Its not possible to use .NET Framework 4.0 with Visual Studio 2012" **what**? Sure it is!

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - When I installed Visual Studio 2012 .NET Framework 4.5 was installed which is an in-place upgrade to .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: What is the declaration for `uploadStream`?

Comment: Sure looks to me like the images are different. Are you sure you're using the same image on both systems?

Comment: @Ramhound, you can still target .NET 4.0 in VS 2012.

Comment: `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary` is missing.  Using base64 encoding would be wise.

Comment: @AlastairPitts - I never say you couldn't but the actual files being used are .NET Framework 4.5 files.

Comment: @Ramhound: only on machines with 4.5.

Comment: @sixlettervariables - I am aware of that.  I never said you could not target 4.0.

Comment: Based on my own experience, I would say that encoding issues between Windows XP and Vista (as well as posterior Windows versions) often derive from the fact that Unicode support in XP isn't on by default. That often causes quirky character-set mistakes. While I can't affirm that's your case, I would check if Unicode is enabled on your XP machine: Start > Control Panel > Date, Time, Language and Regional Options > Regional and Language Options > Languages > Supplemental language support > 'Install files for complex script and right to left languages (including thai)' must be checked.

Comment: @Ramhound: And I quote "Its not possible to use .NET Framework 4.0 with Visual Studio 2012."

Comment: @AlastairPitts - When you target .NET Framework 4.0 with .NET Framework 4.5 installed your still using the .NET Framework 4.5 assemblies. I should have used the word **install** .NET Framework 4.0 if Visual Studio 2012 and .NET Framework 4.5 is installed.

Comment: The bitmap operations found in .NET are backed by the Windows API. The PixelFormat is important and you may have been using the wrong value. The InterpolationMode will not cause you problems... you can change it back to HighQuality. That's just defining the resize filter.

Comment: @Scot Thank you for the explanation. I'll see if I can change it when I get back to work. OnoSendai: Well I've found a solution, but I'll look into that as well, thank you. I hope I can do without having to check those settings because the program is running on many client PCs and it would suck having to check all the xp-machines.

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP and newer os'es like 7 and 8 are encoding and decoding things differently. What i can suggest for you is encode your byte array into BASE64 before transferring. Then receive it  and decode back to your byte array. .Net has easy methods to encode and decode base64. Since base64 text is 7 bit ascii there will be no problem transferring it.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. @Crimson, I'll check into the encoding when I get back to work (On study leave now). And thanks for explaining it. I couldn't be sure if it was an encoding issue or not and didn't want to waste time charging off in all directions.